# Opening and Edit PDF Form in IOS App

Tags: ios, pdf

I am developing a iOS application using Xcode.

1. I Have a PDF form (where I can enter fill the fields like name, age, email id, etc).
2. I want to integrate the PDF into my app, and allow user to fill that PDF form.
3. By default a UI Webview does not allow same.

How to enable PDF form editing in iOS App, is there any plugin I can integrate or some way to workaround it.

Also my second important question is: Can I open a Intenet Explorer Web view on iOS App? Since the web view I am planning to integrate only works on IE Browser.

Comment: As I know we can't edit the PDFs using the Standard iOS SDK.

Comment: Not Android related topic, remove tag

Comment: Yes ! Is there any plugin or something which we can use to edit same.

Comment: @SamBains Also i wanted to know how i can achieve same in Andriod ! Forgot to mention that in question

Comment: Hi, have you got something ?